# float:left even if parent div is too small

Tags: html, css

The issue I am facing here has to do with the fact that the total width of the child divs is larger than the width of the parent div. I need the child divs to float to the left of each other even if they overflow the parent div.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="gallery_container">
    <div id="viewport">
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="images/1/1.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="images/1/2.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="images/1/3.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.gallery_container {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #171717;
}

#viewport {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery_img_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.gallery_img {
    height: 95%;
}
```

How can I get all divs with of **class gallery_img_container** to float to the left of each other? I've tried adding `float:left` **.gallery_img_container** but it doesn't do anything. They go underneath each other instead of side by side.

Another note is that **.gallery_img_container** must have the `display:flex` property

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: **.gallery_img_container** must have the `width:100%` property

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comments.

```css
.gallery_container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #171717;
}
#viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.gallery_img_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.gallery_img {
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_container">
  <div id="viewport">
    <div class="gallery_img_container">
      <img src="images/1/1.png" class="gallery_img">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_img_container">
      <img src="images/1/2.png" class="gallery_img">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_img_container">
      <img src="images/1/3.png" class="gallery_img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question, .gallery_container must have display: flex;

Answer (score 0):

You have "width:100%;" applied to the ".gallery_img_container" class causing each container to break into next line, remove this and add "float: left;" then it will work.

Comment: That is the problem. The total width of the children is greater than the parent. Is there anyway to still make them float left? I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: lol the edit changes the question entirely, doesn't make sense keeping the "width:100%;" in attempt to solve your problem. A width of 100% is just that, fully spanning the row, unless you position it absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Farasat,

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Let me see if I can confirm what I think you are seeking.  You want to achieve a result where you have a set of images which are, collectively, wider than #viewport, but you want them to keep "piling up" to the right.  That is, you don't want them to wrap.  If we consider [] the bounds of the viewport and @ to be an image, you want (for example), something like this:

[@]@@

Is this right?

If so, I think a key thing to note is that your gallery_img_container is of display flex, which means it is a block, not inline, style.  This will cause the gallery_img_containers to stack, not flow to the right.

I think all you need to do is to say "white-space: nowrap;" in #viewport (to keep things from wrapping), and then to make gallery_img_container to be of type inline-flex, so that they do not stack.

I'm attaching an example to hopefully demonstrate what I mean (notes: I just grabbed a random image off the web to make this more concrete.  Also note that since your gallery_img_container is 100%, each image is the size of the #viewport. I'm not sure if that's what you want).

```css
.gallery_container {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
}

#viewport {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.gallery_img_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.gallery_img {
    height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_container">
    <div id="viewport">
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="https://wildfiregames.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2016_07/elephant.png.d12017f872cf14f8b046706f497701ba.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="https://wildfiregames.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2016_07/elephant.png.d12017f872cf14f8b046706f497701ba.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_img_container">
            <img src="https://wildfiregames.com/forum/uploads/monthly_2016_07/elephant.png.d12017f872cf14f8b046706f497701ba.png" class="gallery_img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Farasat, did any of these answers address your question?